# C# wrap multiple elements in one element in XML

Tags: c#, xml

How do I wrap multiple elements within an element in an XML file?

I have code that creates an XDocument like so:

```
 doc = new XDocument(
     new System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty),
     new XElement("JobSvc",
         new XAttribute("environment", this.environment),
         new XAttribute("dateTo", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()),
         new XAttribute("dateFrom", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7).ToShortDateString())
     ));
     return doc;
```

and then I have code that adds elements to this document, such as:

```
  public void Append_ProcessName_Server_Type(XDocument doc)
  {//i will replace confidential info
      var name_Type_Server = new XElement("Wrapper",
                                 new XAttribute("x","******"),
                                 new XAttribute("x","x"),
                                 new XAttribute("x","x"));
      doc.Root.Add(name_Type_Server);
  }
```

then I add more elements under the element created above with this:

```
 public void AppendExtractedRowsAsElements(XDocument doc)
 {
     var newElement = new XElement("processId", this.id,
                          new XAttribute("duration", this.duration),
                          new XAttribute("eventTime", this.eventTime),
                          new XAttribute("source", this.source),
                          new XAttribute("runNumber", run));
     doc.Root.Add(newElement);
 }
```

this works fine and produces an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JobSvc dateAndTimeExecuted="2015-06-29T14:38:48.588082+08:00" environment="" dateFrom="6/22/2015" dateTo="6/29/2015">
  <process server="xxx" type="x" name="x" />
  <processId duration="12182" eventTime="6/5/2015 6:23:02 AM" source="***" runNumber="1">xxxxxx</processId>
  <processId duration="6574" eventTime="6/12/2015 4:47:36 AM" source="***" runNumber="2">xxxxxx</processId>
```

how do I make it output like this: where all the processid elements are wrapped by the process element?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <JobSvc dateAndTimeExecuted="2015-06-29T14:38:48.588082+08:00" environment="" dateFrom="6/22/2015" dateTo="6/29/2015">
      <process server="xxx" type="x" name="x" >
      <processId duration="12182" eventTime="6/5/2015 6:23:02 AM" source="***" runNumber="1">xxxxxx</processId>
      <processId duration="6574" eventTime="6/12/2015 4:47:36 AM" source="***" runNumber="2">xxxxxx</processId>
</process>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add newly created `processId` elements to the wrapper element instead of the document's root element, for example :

```
public void AppendExtractedRowsAsElements(XDocument doc)
{
    ......
    var process = doc.Root.Element("process");
    process.Add(newElement);
}
```

Comment: how does this work?
where will I use the var process?

Comment: @GianMarcoTe oops, posted too soon. I should've added `newElement` to variable `process`. Fixed

Comment: it was able to compile and install without errors but it gave me a log saying

`SampleMonitoringService: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: and it does not write to the xml file :(

Comment: removing var process eliminates the exception, but im still stuck with my original problem lol

Comment: 1. Order of execution matters, make sure you have added `process` element before executing `AppendExtractedRowsAsElements()`. 2. When you save the `XDocument` object back to file? Make sure you save it back after all modifications done

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `doc.Root.Add(newElement);`. This adds the element to the root. 

Try this instead:

```
public void AppendExtractedRowsAsElements(XDocument doc, XElement parent)
{
   var newElement = new XElement("processId", this.id,
                    new XAttribute("duration", this.duration),
                    new XAttribute("eventTime", this.eventTime),
                    new XAttribute("source", this.source),
                    new XAttribute("runNumber", run));
   parent.Add(newElement);

}
```

Call like following:

```
AppendExtractedRowsAsElements(doc,name_Type_Server);
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didnt work :( and it didn't write anything to the xml at all. it was able to compile and install without errors though

Comment: @GianMarcoTe It should work. Can you show your main function?

Comment: @GianMarcoTe Just show the other part of the code. I want to see how  you call those methods.

Comment: see my edit. those are the ones in my class which i instantiate and access in the method that is being called in the onstart of my windows service.

Answer (score 0):

You can build it simply with XDocument.Parse(string)

```
        static XDocument MakeDoc()
        {
            string input =  
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                "<JobSvc environment=\"" + this.environment + "\"\n" +
                " dateTo=\"" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + "\"\n" +
                " dateFrom=\"" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7).ToShortDateString() + "\"\n" +
                "/>\n";


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            return doc;
        }​
```